# Combination of ohlc and line plot in highchart

Tags: highcharts

Can I have a plot which is a combination of both ohlc and line plot without time range using Highcharts/Highstock?

Answer (score 2):

You should use two series (first ohlc and second line).

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZAR5/1/

```
series: [{
        type: 'ohlc',
        data: [
            [1147996800000, 63.26, 64.88, 62.82, 64.51],
            [1148256000000, 63.87, 63.99, 62.77, 63.38],
            [1148342400000, 64.86, 65.19, 63.00, 63.15],
            [1148428800000, 62.99, 63.65, 61.56, 63.34],
            [1148515200000, 64.26, 64.45, 63.29, 64.33],
            [1148601600000, 64.31, 64.56, 63.14, 63.55],
            [1148947200000, 63.29, 63.30, 61.22, 61.22],
            [1149033600000, 61.76, 61.79, 58.69, 59.77]
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        data: [
            [1147996800000, 63.26],
            [1148256000000, 63.87],
            [1148342400000, 64.86],
            [1148428800000, 62.99],
            [1148515200000, 64.26],
            [1148601600000, 64.31],
            [1148947200000, 63.29],
            [1149033600000, 61.76]
        ]
    }]
```

Disabling navigator: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.enabled
rangeselector: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.enabled