# Highcharts Highstock How to Plot OHLC and Line Charts from One Set of Embedded CSV Data Using Series Map Tools?

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

This example plots an ohlc and line chart using two versions of the same embedded JSON data:

[Combination of ohlc and line plot in highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601542/combination-of-ohlc-and-line-plot-in-highchart)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZAR5/1/

But it requires two JSON formatted sets of data and the data are redundant.

Instead I would like to keep all data in one embedded CSV format as shown in the non-operative code below. The example chosen would plot OHLC bars and a sample line both stored in the same lines of CSV data. I want to know how to make Highstock recognize the csv in the series specification?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
  AAPL Combined OHLC and Moving Average
</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,open,high,low,close,line1
1147996800000, 63.26, 64.88, 62.82, 64.51,63
1148256000000, 63.87, 63.99, 62.77, 63.38,63
1148342400000, 64.86, 65.19, 63.00, 63.15,64
1148428800000, 62.99, 63.65, 61.56, 63.34,63
1148515200000, 64.26, 64.45, 63.29, 64.33,64
1148601600000, 64.31, 64.56, 63.14, 63.55,64
1148947200000, 63.29, 63.30, 61.22, 61.22,63
1149033600000, 61.76, 61.79, 58.69, 59.77,62
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
        },
        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
series: [{
        type: 'ohlc',
        data: ? how to pass date and ohlc values via csv data?
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        data: ? how to pass date and line1 values via csv data? 
    }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code below is similar to my approach and does not give a result. It is taken from the question and answer under this link:

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33408

```html
$(function () {
    $('#column').highcharts({
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: {
                csv: document.getElementById('column_csv').innerHTML
            }
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Company Total Sales',
            data: {
                csv: document.getElementById('column_csv2').innerHTML
            },
            center: [100, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

The question and answer under this link suggest that there is a solution to my problem using series mapping tools in Highstock:

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39714

http://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/k6z0scvq/

The format of CSV is in the question:

```
Fecha, Direccion, Velocidad del Viento
2017/10/06 12:10, 44.5257, 230.173
2017/10/06 12:20, 47.424, 230.387
2017/10/06 12:30, 48.5546, 232.287
2017/10/06 12:40, 51.1385, 230.373
2017/10/06 12:50, 48.7313, 233.013
2017/10/06 13:00, 47.6305, 233.94
2017/10/06 13:10, 48.0115, 233.84
2017/10/06 13:20, 47.1394, 232.713
```

The answer using series mapping:

```
data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
    seriesMapping: [{
        x: 0,
        value: 1,
        direction: 2
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 1
    }],     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map your csv data to the proper series data structure:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
  seriesMapping: [{
    x: 0,
    open: 1,
    high: 2,
    low: 3,
    close: 4
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 5
  }]
},
series: [{
  type: 'ohlc'
}, {
  type: 'line'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/da74pokt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping